# Automated webpage browsing

Tags: automation, wireshark, browsing, tshark

I want to find a way to open https websites in my browser (or any other script-based way??) while running tshark or wireshark. My goal is to collect the ssl dialogues and then via tshark I can export the ssl parameters to a csv format for further analysis.

Obviously, I can't browse the whole day, so is there a way to automate this process somehow?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Well, I was pointed in this forum because the network engineering guys told me it was irrelevant to post the question there. I haven't really tried some coding, I was hoping that there might be already some kind of open source software that could automate this process.

Comment: Consider headless browsers, like [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)